# Amplify Auth.signOut() in React Navigation Drawer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, aws-amplify

I am a JS noob and a React/React-Native noob so this issue is probably something easy to solve. I am using React Navigation 6.X, React 16.13.1. I have a Drawer Navigator:

```
function MainNav(props) {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home">
        { screenProps => <Home {...screenProps} updateAuth={props.updateAuth} />}
      </Drawer.Screen>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Route2">
        { screenProps => <Route2 {...screenProps} updateAuth={props.updateAuth} />}
      </Drawer.Screen>
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I am passing the following as an item/button to be added to the drawer with an async function to sign out the user upon pressing the item/button:

```
function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
    async function signOut() {
        try {
            await Auth.signOut();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error signing out: ', error);
        }
    }
    
    return (
      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        <DrawerItemList {...props} />
        <DrawerItem
          label="Sign Out"
          onPress={() => signOut}
        />
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
    );
}
```

Why does this button not do anything upon pressing it?

My alternative attempt is to re-config this item as a class like this:

```
class CustomDrawerContent extends React.Component {
    signOut = async () => {
        try {
          await Auth.signOut()
          console.log('signed out')
          this.props.updateAuth('auth')
        } catch (err) {
          console.log('error signing out...', err)
        }
      }
    
    render() {
    return (
      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        <DrawerItemList {...props} />
        <DrawerItem
          label="Sign Out"
          onPress={() => this.signOut}
        />
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
    );}
}
```

Which either yields: `ReferenceError: props is not defined`

Or upon deleting the `{...props}` code: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined`, where we see that the App class with the point of error annotated with a comment below:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currentView: 'initializing'
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkAuth()
  }
  updateAuth = (currentView) => {
    this.setState({ currentView })
  }
  checkAuth = async () => {
    try {
      await AmplifyAuth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      console.log('user is signed in')
      this.setState({ currentView: 'mainNav' }) // <----ERROR HERE
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('user is not signed in')
      this.setState({ currentView: 'auth' })
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { currentView } = this.state
    console.log('currentView: ', currentView)
    return (
      <>
        { currentView === 'initializing' && <Initializing />}
        { currentView === 'auth' && <Auth updateAuth={this.updateAuth} />}
        { currentView === 'mainNav' && <MainNav updateAuth={this.updateAuth} />}
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

So I think I'm on the right path, but, how do I define the route of this class properly? Or, is there some way I may be able to simply call the `Auth.signOut` as shown in my first attempt?

Sorry for my lack of understanding in advance, again, first time doing anything with JS. Thanks for the help!

Comment: your alternative attempt should work. If you want to do `Auth.signOut`, you have to declare `Auth` as a context on the root level. But more or less it's based on your alternative approach.

Comment: So with my alternative method (making `CustomDrawerContent` a class), I'm still getting the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined`. I'm going to try to extend the Home component which seems to be working perfectly fine with the exact same structure as `CustomDrawerContent`

*Update: didn't work, same error*